# Windows 8 PHP push notifications

Tags: php, windows-8, push-notification

Is it currently supported that I send toast push notifications to a Windows 8 store app using php server side script like on Windows Phone.

I was able to find the below php code to send push notifications to a Windows 8 store app but doesn't seem to support toast notifications.

```
<?php
class WPNTypesEnum{       
const Toast = 'wns/toast';
const Badge = 'wns/badge';
const Tile  = 'wns/tile';
const Raw   = 'wns/raw';
}                         

class WPNResponse{
public $message = '';
public $error = false;
public $httpCode = '';

function __construct($message, $httpCode, $error = false){
    $this->message = $message;
    $this->httpCode = $httpCode;
    $this->error = $error;
}
}

class WPN{            
private $access_token = '';
private $sid = '';
private $secret = '';

function __construct($sid, $secret){
    $this->sid = $sid;
    $this->secret = $secret;
}

private function get_access_token(){
    if($this->access_token != ''){
        return;
    }

    $str = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$this->sid&client_secret=$this->secret&scope=notify.windows.com";
    $url = "https://login.live.com/accesstoken.srf";

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$str");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);                       

    $output = json_decode($output);

    if(isset($output->error)){
        throw new Exception($output->error_description);
    }

    $this->access_token = $output->access_token;
}

public function build_tile_xml($title, $img){
    return '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>'.
    '<tile>'.
      '<visual lang="en-US">'.
        '<binding template="TileWideImageAndText01">'.
          '<image id="1" src="'.$img.'"/>'.
          '<text id="1">'.$title.'</text>'.
        '</binding>'.
      '</visual>'.
    '</tile>';
}

public function post_tile($uri, $xml_data, $type = WPNTypesEnum::Tile, $tileTag = ''){
    if($this->access_token == ''){
        $this->get_access_token();
    }

    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/xml', "Content-Length: " . strlen($xml_data), "X-WNS-Type: $type", "Authorization: Bearer $this->access_token");
    if($tileTag != ''){
        array_push($headers, "X-WNS-Tag: $tileTag");
    }

    $ch = curl_init($uri);
    # Tiles: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868263.aspx
    # http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465435.aspx
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$xml_data");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $response = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close($ch);

    $code = $response['http_code'];
    if($code == 200){
        return new WPNResponse('Successfully sent message', $code);
    }
    else if($code == 401){
        $this->access_token = '';
        return $this->post_tile($uri, $xml_data, $type, $tileTag);
    }
    else if($code == 410 || $code == 404){
        return new WPNResponse('Expired or invalid URI', $code, true);
    }
    else{
        return new WPNResponse('Unknown error while sending message', $code, true);
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: After a quick read of the Microsoft documentation, it seems that you need to change the root tag of the XML to toast. Also you need to change the value of the template attribute in the binding tag to one of the toast templates in the app you want to send the push notification to. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh868252.aspx